# Android PreferenceFragment No view found for id for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, preferencefragment

So I'm making an android application and I started dealing with preferences, when I simply use a PreferenceActivity, everything works perfectly, however, if I use it with a PreferenceFragment, it crashes right after I click the button that calls intents to SettingsActivity with an error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*app package*/*app package*.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08003d for fragment SettingsFragment{41cc1a98 #0 id=0x7f08003d}
```

this is SettingsActivity:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);
        // Display the fragment as the main content.
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.pager, new SettingsFragment())
                .commit();
    }


    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

        }
    }
}
```

R.id.pager is only a simple viewPager layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/pager"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

my preference xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_sync"
        android:title="Sync?"
        android:summary="Do u wanna sync?"
        android:defaultValue="true" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I'm still quite new to android so any help would be awesome!! Thanks!!

**EDIT:**
Problem solved in comments of correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_layout)` before

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.pager, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks! but although adding this line stops the error, it shows an empty screen....

Comment: @ytt You are using a `ViewPager` so you need to set an adapter. If you want to show just one `Fragment` use a `FrameLayout`

Comment: I'm using a `ViewPager` because the homescreen of the app is a `ViewPager` and the Settings button is on the `ActionBar`... What should I do?

Comment: Start a new `Activity` with the `Fragment`

Comment: So I call `SettingsActivity` which calls `SettingsFragment` and `SettingsFragment` will call another `Activity` is that what you mean??

Comment: Is `SettingsActivity` the homescreen of the app?

Comment: Then you can set the new layout in the `SettingsActivity` and add the `Fragment` in that layout can't you?